# Is it possible to examine a file . ad1 with autopsy?

Tags: memory, computer-forensics

I have to examine a file ".ad1" .
Usually I use autopsy [I’m on windows] for memory analysis but with files ".ad1" I can't do it, can you help me to use it on autopsy or do I have to use another tool?
Every time I upload the file to the software it shows me that it is completely empty and autopsy finds nothing.

Every time I upload the file to the software it shows me that it is completely empty and autopsy finds nothing.
The tool shows me only the hex dump

Comment: maybe autopsy can't handle it, take FTK or xmount and convert it to a dd or e01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can.
Use this [Plugin](https://github.com/markmckinnon/Autopsy-Plugins/tree/master/AD1_Extractor)

Reference: https://tmairi.github.io/posts/dissecting-the-ad1-file-format/